# How to break line in mobile view but not desktop?

Tags: bootstrap-4

So I have got the desktop view how I want it took look. See image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Ep2.jpg

But for mobile, it looks likes this. I want to have a line break or padding in the middle of the two cards but not have it show on desktop. How would I do this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="card bg-dark p-1 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div class="card border-0 rounded-0">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card bg-dark p-1 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div class="card border-0 rounded-0">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give some padding for divs under .row, you also can give margin at some point of mobile view like I have given for media query for 767

```css
@media screen and (max-width : 767px) {
.row div{
padding:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="card bg-dark p-1 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div class="card border-0 rounded-0">
a
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card bg-dark p-1 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div class="card border-0 rounded-0">
b
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```